# Logarithmic Function Property

Tags: logarithms

We know that if $${\log_ap > m => 0 < p < a^m,\qquad if\quad 0 < a < 1}$$
I checked for ${\log_{0.5}0 = ∞}$.
 Here ${a=0.5, p=0}$ and let ${m =1}$.
I get ${0 ≤ 0 < 0.5 = 0 ≤ 0 < 0.5}$.

Here upon the equality being added in ${0 ≤ 0 < 0.5}$, is the original property getting violated which only includes strict inequality?

Comment: Mistake. Fixed it @Joe.

Comment: How do you get the '$=$' in $0 \le 1 < 0.5 = 0 \le 0 < 0.5$?

Answer (score 2):

The function $\log_ap$ is defined for $p > 0$ only. So writing $\log_{0.5} 0 $ does not make sense and any further inequalites do not hold.

Answer (score 1):

According to [definition of logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) in $ log_b{x} $, $x$ must be greater than 0 or $x>0$. Thus $log _{0.5} {0}$ is wrong as here $x$ is not greater than $1$.